# Limpiar combobox en vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

Hola quisiera saber como puedo limpiar un combobox en vue js con quasar, al realizar un guardado de datos en un formulario mis combobox no se limpian y me gustaría saber como puedo hacer esa acción, estos son los combobox que deseo limpiar:

```
itemsLinea: [],
        itemsModulo: [],
        itemsEstacion: [],
```

Y este es el método donde me gustaría que al guardar se limpiaran automáticamente:

```
  guardarEstacion() {
                this.$v.$touch()
                if(!this.$v.$invalid ) {     
                    let object = {
                
                    idDispositivo: this.proptabla_detalle.cabecera.id_dispositivo,
                    idEstacion : this.idEstacion.value,
                    idModulo : this.idModulo.value,
                    idLinea : this.idLinea.value,
       
                    }
                    console.log("OBJETO ", object)
                    this.$q.loading.show()
                    this.$store.dispatch("Dispositivos/CREARESTACION_ACTION", {obj: object}).then(res => {
                    const {resultado} = this.CREARESTACION_GETTER            
                        if(resultado) {                                                            
                            this.$router.push('/dispositivos');                                                                      
                            this.$q.notify({
                            message: 'El registro ha sido creado exitosamente',
                            timeout: 3000,
                            type: 'positive',
                            position: 'bottom-left'
                        })     
                        }
                        if(res.data.error){
                            this.$q.notify({
                                message: res.data.error,
                                timeout: 3000,
                                type: 'warning',
                                position: 'bottom-left'
                            })
                        }
                          
                        this.cargaTablaDetalle(this.proptabla_detalle.cabecera.id_dispositivo) 
                        this.$q.loading.hide()                       
                    }).catch(err => {
                        console.error("ERROR", err)
                    })
                },
```

Comment: Y probaste simplemente limpiar las lineas como cuando las definis?

Comment: Como sería eso?